# Segmentation fault(core dumped) in linked lists C

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have a problem in this piece of code with linked lists. It gives me the error:

```
 Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)
```

Can anyone see what seems to be the problem? Thanks in advance.

`pos` stands for position and `root` for the first element

```
typedef struct
{
  element *root;
  int size;
} list;

typedef struct _element
{
  char *str;
  struct _element *next;
} element;

int
insert_list (list * lst, const char *value, int pos)
{
  element *new;

  int k;
  new = malloc (sizeof (element));

  for (k = 0; k < pos; k++)
    {
      new = lst->root;
      lst->root = lst->root->next;

      if (k == pos - 1)
        {
          lst->root = NULL;
          new->str = value;
        }
    }

  for (k = 0; k <= lst->size; k++)
    {
      new = lst->root;
      lst->root = lst->root->next;

      if (k == lst->size)
        {
          lst->root = NULL;
          new->str = value;
        }
      if (pos < 0 || pos >= lst->size)
        return -1;
      else
        return pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `first`? You dereference it before any assignment!

Comment: Show how you call the function.

Comment: Hello, you are right, i forgot to declare the variable, but the problem still maintains, any idea?

Comment: The function is called correctly, since it was already given to us, we only need to develop the functions

Comment: lst == NULL ? and new = malloc(sizeof(element)); for(k=0;k<pos;k++) { new = lst->root; is weird

Comment: Basically, i'm emptying the root of the list, so i can insert a new one, not sure if its correct though...

Comment: Which line throws the segfault?

Comment: @opd That is the question.

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger?

Comment: no, im compiling in the standart windows console, so i dont really have a debbuger

Comment: so, am i destroying the list by erasing its root?

Comment: `lst->root = NULL;` ... `new = lst->root;` ... `new->str = value;` : `NULL->str = value` Seg-fault. and `lst->root = lst->root->next;` : lst->root` ,They've been overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see how to debug this.

First of all, compile your code with warnings, and read the warnings:

```
$ gcc -Wall x.c -o xx.c:6:3: error: unknown type name ‘element’
x.c: In function ‘insert_list’:
x.c:26:11: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
x.c:27:28: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
x.c:32:20: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
x.c:38:11: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
x.c:39:28: error: request for member ‘next’ in something not a structure or union
x.c:44:20: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
x.c:51:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

All of those things are problems, and 2 (the errors) indicate the code you posted would *never have compiled*

So, you have problems beyond a segmentation fault. The first one is this line:

```
 lst->root = lst->root->next;
```

This is because you need to define the `element` `struct` before the `list` `struct`.

Apart from this, your insert routine is broken:

```
new = malloc (sizeof (element));

for (k = 0; k < pos; k++)
  {
    new = lst->root;
```

Here you are overwriting your newly allocated `element` many times.

On the next line you overwrite the `root`:

```
  lst->root = lst->root->next;
```

I'm afraid I can't even figure out what you are *trying* to do here. If the goal is to insert an element at position *pos* in a singly linked list, what you want to do is:

1. Allocate a new element `n`.
2. If `pos` is zero, make your new element `n` the root, and make `n->next` point to the current root, and you are done.
3. Else iterate `pos-1` times along the list, call that `x`.
4. Make `n->next->next = x->next` (if `n->next` exists)
5. Make `n->next = x`